# Сортировка xml файла в с#

Tags: c#, xml

Нужно создать проект в Windows Forms, который будет читать xml файл и сортировать его по алфавиту.

Алгоритм:

1. Нажимаю на кнопку "Загрузить файл"
2. Сортировка по алфавиту.
3. Сохраняет файл.
4. Выводит путь до файла.

Вопрос в следующем, после загрузки файла, мы же должны сохранить содержание в переменную(массив) и как это сделать?

```
<ROOT><ROW InteractionId="" contact="" openTime="" openedBy="" description="affectedService="" resolution="" category="запрос" closeTime="" closedBy="" resolutionCode="" firstTouch="" impact="2" affectedCI="АНОНИМ" briefDescription="" status="1-Новое" timeActualStart="" timeActualEnd="" templateName="" affectedSystem="" slaExpired="" externalId="" callbackContact="" rzdBranch="" userId="000000" fullPhone="" morePhone="" rzdEmail="kovaleva" city="ЧИТА" street="" room="" dept="" position="Технолог " affectedItem="" arriveType="" ipAddress="" wrongContact="" verified="" helpdeskAgent="" recordid=""/><ROW /></ROOT>
```

Comment: Пример входных и выходных данных? При чем здесь winforms, если вопрос не про UI? Что именно не получается? Про сериализацию и десереализацию слышали?

Comment: Входные данные: InteractionId = "": contact="": openTime="" и д.р. Мне надо, чтобы все эти данные встали по алфавиту.

Comment: Это не XML, приведите пример входного и выходного XML прямо в вопросе, не надо это в комментарий писать.

Comment: _Мне надо, чтобы все эти данные встали по алфавиту._ по алфавиту чего? У вас куча аттрибутов, по какому сортировать?

Answer (score 1):

Если кроме сортировки больше ничего не нужно, то я бы использовал Linq to Xml. С его помощью код получается простейшим.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var sortedRows = xml
    .Elements("ROW")
    .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute("InteractionId")?.Value)    
    .ToList();

xml.RemoveAll();
xml.Add(sortedRows);

xml.Save("sorted.xml");
```

Укажите тот атрибут, по которому нужно сортировать.
Свойство `.Value` имеет тип `string`. Если вместо строки нужна сортировка по числу, дате-времени и т. п., то используем приведение типа:

```
.OrderBy(x => (int?)x.Attribute("impact"))
```